# Referencing .net(4.7.1) projects in .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I have a .net Core 2.2 project. This is created using a Webapplication (Model View Controller) template. I can add my .Net Framework 4.7.1 projects into this core project, it compiles, run - and is deployed on my test servers.

1) Then I read about 2.2 End of Life, and I tried to migrate this to 3.1, and I cannot reference .Net Framework 4.7.1 in 3.1 framework. I don't know what is my next step here.

2)I read that I can convert my dll's to .Net Standard and reference - but, how can I do this?

3)These 4.7.1 dll's are shared by .Net Framework projects and core projects, so if I change this to .Net Standard - will my .Net Framework applications work?

4) Also - should I migrate my 2.2 Core projects to 3.0 because of the EOL? Is that mandatory? How will EOL affect audits if I don't migrate?

Answer (score 1):

First, 2.2 is EOL, because 2.1 is the LTS release. You can downgrade to 2.1 if you don't want to jump to 3.x yet, and you'll still have a year or two of support there, I think.

However, 3.x takes the first step towards the new vision of one .NET (.NET 5 for all workflows), so the sooner you can get there, the better. 3.1, specifically, is the LTS release for 3.x, so stick there if you don't want to be forced to upgrade again for a while.

.NET Core 3.x implements .NET Standard 2.1, which is why you can no longer target .NET Framework with that (no version of .NET Framework implements .NET Standard 2.1 and never will). However, .NET Standard 2.0 is supported by both .NET Core (2.x and 3.x) and .NET Framework 4.6.1+. As a result, if you need to share a library between all these targets, you should target .NET Standard 2.0.

As far as converting your existing libraries go, you simply change the target framework to .NET Standard 2.0. That's literally it. Once you do that, some functionality in the library may fail (anything that *requires* .NET Framework, i.e. Windows-specific APIs). At that point, you either need to rewrite those parts of the library to use .NET Standard-compatible APIs, or use compiler directives to sub-in alternate implementations for .NET Standard 2.0/.NET Core, at which point, you'd have to multi-target the library (i.e. .NET Framework *and* .NET Standard 2.0 or even specifically .NET Core). When compiling, DLLs will be generated for each specific target, allowing you to seamless reference the same library from projects targeting any of the library targets.

If you're doing anything with ASP.NET Core components in your libraries, you should factor that code out into separate libraries and target .NET Core 3.1 directly there. There's no point in targeting .NET Standard 2.1, as that code will only ever be applicable to .NET Core, anyways. You should also work in the opposite direction. In other words, if there's anything that's *only* applicable to .NET Framework projects (Web Forms, etc.), then factor that out into separate libraries that will only target .NET Framework. That will allow you to migrate the remaining parts of the library more easily to .NET Standard 2.0.